# deploymentURL not injected into integration test with Arquillian Drone

Tags: java, testing, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to introduce integration testing using Arquillian Drone in our project. I did some  small demo apps, read some stuff and finally tried to write a simple integration test for relatively simple web page.

I think I've resolved all required dependencies and I was able to run my test class inside Intellij Idea. But when I run it I am getting an exception saying:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup value for field java.net.URL com.example.BEViewUIWithDrone.deploymentURL (...)

Caused by:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for type class java.net.URL returned a null value: org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.enricher.resource.URLResourceProvider@6e73a35c
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.lookup(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:115)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:57)" (full stack trace lower)

My test class:

```
public class BEViewUIWithDrone extends Arquillian {

    private static final String WEBAPP_SRC = "project/src/main/webapp";

    @Drone
    private DefaultSelenium selenium;

    @ArquillianResource
    URL deploymentURL;


    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

        MavenDependencyResolver resolver = DependencyResolvers
                .use(MavenDependencyResolver.class)
                .loadDependenciesFromPom("pom.xml");

        File[] jbossLogging = resolver.artifact("org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.0.0.GA").resolveAsFiles();
        File[] solder = resolver.artifact("org.jboss.seam.solder:seam-solder:3.0.0.Final").resolveAsFiles();

        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "be-view.war")
                .addAsLibraries(jbossLogging)
                .addAsLibraries(solder)
                .addClasses(BorrowingEntityService.class)
                .addClasses(BorrowingEntityViewService.class)
                .addClasses(ViewingService.class)
                .addClasses(QueryLimit.class)
                .addClasses(CustomerService.class)
                .addClasses(MockProducer.class)
                .addAsWebResource(new File(WEBAPP_SRC, "view/be/borrowingEntityView.xhtml"))
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(
                        new StringAsset("<faces-config version=\"2.0\"/>"),
                        "faces-config.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {

        // When
        selenium.open(deploymentURL + "/view/be/searchBorrowingEntityView.jsf");
    }
}
```

Pom fragment: [link to pastie.org with listing](http://pastie.org/private/fiav0lcpwkwczcdypznaa)

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup value for field java.net.URL com.example.BEViewUIWithDrone.deploymentURL
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:61)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeTest(Arquillian.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:525)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:202)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:613)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:964)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:110)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for type class java.net.URL returned a null value: org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.enricher.resource.URLResourceProvider@6e73a35c
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.lookup(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:57)
    ... 75 more
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Weld-EE-Embedded container is only an CDI Bean Container and does not support anything beyond simple CDI.

To test JSF you'll need a container with JSF support, e.g. JBoss AS 7.

Comment: @xybrek Was it your deployment method? I accidentally removed my \@Deployment annotation while adding another line (don't ask me how). So with anyone using a container with support for JSF check you haven't been a plonker like me!